# strange Framing.delimiter behavior

Tags: java, akka-stream

I am trying to use Akka Stream to process a large file (source is a file, sink is a simple `println` sink), and here is my code:

```
final Path file = Paths.get("f:/someFile");

// sink, do something interesting later
Sink<ByteString, CompletionStage<Done>> printlnSink = Sink.<ByteString>foreach(chunk -> {
    String line = chunk.utf8String();  // turn each chunk to a String
    System.out.println(line);
});

// flow, which has a chunk size
ByteString separator1 = ByteString.fromString(".");    // this will work
ByteString separator2 = ByteString.fromString(".\n");  // this will NOT work
final Flow<ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed> flow = Framing.delimiter(separator1, 1000, FramingTruncation.ALLOW);

// put them together and let it run
CompletionStage<IOResult> ioResult = FileIO
        .fromPath(file)
        .via(flow)
        .to(printlnSink)
        .run(system);
```

so if I use `separator1` to `Framing.delimiter(...)`, it will work fine, but if I use `separator2` to `Framing.delimiter(...)`, it will not work at all.

Here is part of the file I want to process:

```
@prefix ns1: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix ns2: <http://hadatac.org/ont/hasco/> .
@prefix ns3: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sio: <http://semanticscience.org/resource/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

ns2:Cohort a owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf <http://purl.org/twc/HHEAR_00050> .

ns2:wasApprovedBy a owl:AnnotationProperty .
```

As you can tell, I cannot use a single `.` as the separator because it happens in the middle of the sentence in many places. That is why I need to use `.\n` as the separator, which does not work.

Can someone help me to check what did I do wrong?

**UPDATE**:

here is my imports:

```
import akka.Done;
import akka.NotUsed;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.japi.Pair;
import akka.stream.*;
import akka.stream.javadsl.*;
import akka.util.ByteString;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
```

I am using Java 8, and here is my build file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.3"
val AkkaVersion = "2.6.10"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % AkkaVersion
```

Comment: that is very strange. I copied your code and I used both separators. Both are working. Now I am not sure if I paste my code here or if I ask you to put your imports and akka version.

Comment: @Felipe, thank you very much for looking into this. Please see my Update in the original question - I pasted my imports and akka version.

Comment: @Felipe, I got it to work, the only thing I changed was here, `Framing.delimiter(separator2, 1000, FramingTruncation.ALLOW)`, changing from `1000` to `10000` made it work just fine. Thank you again for looking into this.

Comment: on the other hand, it is hard to believe even the original 1000 is not enough... the first line in the file does not have a length of 1000.... Also, truncation is set to `ALLOW`, not sure how could Akka just stop processing. I guess need to read its source code to understand that.